# How do I get text from sheet1 from multiple columns, to show up in sheet2 into rows?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to create a formula that basically says "Anywhere on sheet1 in `B2:D6` where there is text in the columns and ignoring all cells that are blank, automatically make that text appear in sheet2 under the corresponding columns"

I tried something like:

```
VLOOKUP(#NAME?,Sheet1!$B$2:$D$6,#NAME?,"")
```

I just don't know how to make it search for the cells with text and ignore the blanks on sheet1, and to return the same on sheet2.

I've posted an image below. Thank you so much for any help!

[image: Screenshot.]

Answer (score 1):

You can use this formula in the latest version of O365:

```
=LET(d,B2:D6,TOROW(FILTER(d,TAKE(d,,1)<>"")))
```

[image]

EDIT: Here's a version using Power Query:

Convert your original data into a Table by putting your cursor anywhere in the table and using Ctrl+T.

Go to the Table Design tab and change the Table name to "data" (the Table Name box is on the left of the Table Design tab).

Then use Data>Get Data>From Other Sources>Blank Query.

This will open the Power Query editor.

Then use Home>Advanced Editor and replace the code that's there with this code:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="data"]}[Content],

    //remove blank rows
    RemoveNulls = Table.SelectRows(Source,each [Assigned To] <> null)[[Assigned To],[#"Item #"],[#"Serial #"]],

    //convert each record to a sub-list of a list
    ListOfLists = List.Transform(Table.ToRecords(RemoveNulls),each Record.ToList(_)),

    //combine the sub-lists into a single list of values
    Combine = List.Combine(ListOfLists),

    //convert the list into a one-column table
    AsTable = Table.Transpose(Table.FromColumns({Combine})),

    //the original column headers
    Header = Table.ColumnNames(RemoveNulls),

    //convert the column headers to repeats of the original
    ChangeTableHeader = Table.TransformColumnNames(
                            AsTable,
                            each 
                                let 
                                    num = Number.From(Text.Replace(_,"Column","")),
                                    calc = Number.RoundDown((num - 1) / List.Count(Header)) + 1
                                in Header{Number.Mod(num-1,3)} & " " & Text.From(calc)
                        )
in
    ChangeTableHeader
```

Note that it's not possible to have repeated column headers in Power Query, so I have suffixed each with a sequential number.

At the end, use Home>Close & Load on the Power Query ribbon. The result will look like this:

[image]

Comment: OK, buy FYI windows version wouldn't make a diff. Probably your Excel version is not the most recent. Another option is to use Power Query.

Comment: Oh! I'll try to figure out how to use Power Query then, thank you for taking the time to give feedback.

Comment: @user1750890 I've added some instructions for solving this with Power Query. Please take a look.

Comment: Hi @flexyourdata Thank you so much for the Power Query instructions! I can't add comment to your original post because I need 50 reputation points or something. Your instructions work, but if I add or remove a name from the original data, it doesn't automatically reflect the change in the Query. I should have also noted in my original question that the data is meant to change names, item # and serial #'s all the time.

Comment: @user1750890 you need to right click the query result and choose refresh when the data changes.